Practice for fast tile CDN
I am using Amazon Cloud Front to deliver my map tiles to my app.
I have several layers of tiled data, so for any given screen there might be sixty assets needed. Cloud Front supports HTTP/2 and HTTP/3 so I have multiplex requests enabled for my map front end.
Would it be faster to use multiple instances of Cloud Front for tile requests, or does Cloud Front already handle many requests as efficiently as having multiple Cloud Front instances would?
